# Basic Nant task

Tags: c#, build-automation, nant

I'm working on creating a simple Nant script that will utilize the assemblyname::get-version function which is documented here: http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/assemblyname.get-version.html

I'm getting a failure "Unknown function 'version::get-major-version'. The .dll is indeed present in the directory that I'm running nant. Which I'm doing so by opening up the cmd prompt and cd'ing to the directory and using the command 'nant'

Any help is appreciated!

```
<target name="updater">

    <echo message = "Hello!" />
    <echo message="${version::get-major-version(assemblyname::get-version(assemblyname::get-assembly-name('nunit.util.dll')))}" />


</target>
```

Comment: can you provide a link to "n00b alert", I fail to find its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of `assemblyname::get-version`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/assemblyname.get-version.html) contains a bug. If you take a look at the [documentation of version functions](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/index.html#Version) you will find out it should be `version::get-major` instead of `version::get-major-version`.

```
<echo message="${version::get-major(assemblyname::get-version(assemblyname::get-assembly-name('nunit.util.dll')))}" />
```

Comment: I should be able to test this tonight, thank you a ton for the for the response. I'll report back as soon as I can confirm, but you appear to be correct.

Comment: This is great, is there a way to combine the version, major, minor and revision to a single property? I'm a bit new with the combination of variables in NAnt. I'm going to attempt this now, will report back with some code snippits if successful.

Comment: value="assemblyname::get-version(assemblyname::get-assembly-name('hardsetvariable'))